# нужна пагинация под текстом статьи без js

Tags: html, css, pagination

Нашел удобную мне пагинацию на чистом css. мне нужно чтоб радиокнопки были под текстом , а не над!

Полный код тут --> [CodePen](https://codepen.io/zvava/pen/zVqbNN)

```
  <h1 class="title">The Lipsum Times</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <input class="one" type="radio" name="page" checked>
    <input class="two" type="radio" name="page">
    <input class="three" type="radio" name="page">
    <div class="content one"> Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="content two"> Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="content three">Lorem ipsum</div>
  </div>
```

Просто переношу вниз, срабатывает дисплей none для content в сss.
Как быть?

Comment: и исчезает самый первый абзац

Comment: Не срабатывает потому что `input.one:checked ~ .content.one` выбирает следующий эл-т после input, а поскольку инпуты вы вниз переносите то следующего такого блока у них точно не будет.. В css пока что нет селектора "предыдущий эл-т", насколько мне известно.. Значит, или переделывать его надо, или на  js добавить пару строк кода